# How to select the last row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table which contains at least 100 rows. When I want to retrieve an element, I do the following code below. This will return the items which has an id between 11 and 28. My goal is to be able to echo the last items which is 28. How can I achieve this on mysql?

```
SELECT names
FROM item_list
WHERE id >= 10 
LIMIT 18
```

Comment: I want to echo the last items on the page

Comment: did you try `LIMIT 17, 1`?

Comment: This solved my problem^

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless. The fact that it works it down to luck rather than design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original query will actually return rows 10 through 27.

```
| ID |
------
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 20 |
| 21 |
| 22 |
| 23 |
| 24 |
| 25 |
| 26 |
| 27 |
```

To get the 28th row, you can use

```
WHERE id >= 10 
LIMIT 18, 1
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f8a0/3)

Or just

```
LIMIT 27, 1
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f8a0/5)

> The `LIMIT` clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement.
>
> ```
>  SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
>  SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;  # Retrieves rows from the 96th row to the last
> ```
>
> In other words, `LIMIT row_count` is equivalent to `LIMIT 0, row_count`.

Comment: It is returning the very last result which is the 100

Comment: I did as you suggested, I did SELECT names
FROM item_list
WHERE id >= 10
ORDER BY id
DESC
LIMIT 1. It is still giving me the very last result which is 100 instead of 28

Comment: That's very strange, since the demos work as expected. Please tell us what is wrong with the demos, or edit your question to show what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if this is really what you want to do, but these options might be close:

```
SELECT names FROM item_list WHERE id = 28
```

or...

```
SELECT names FROM item_list WHERE id <= 28 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

or even...

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT names FROM item_list WHERE id >= 10 LIMIT 18 ORDER BY id DESC ) LIMIT 1
```

One more (cleaner than the previous, but longer), for fun:

```
SELECT names 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT id, names
        FROM item_list 
        WHERE id >= 10
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 18 ) subQ
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

It isn't 100% clear what you /actually/ want to get as your list changes -- but hopefully these examples will steer you to the right bits of documentation!

Comment: This is giving me an error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: the only missing here is not giving alias on the subquery `:)` i'll update this.

Comment: isn't it necessary to order the subquery as well since it doesn't guarantee the order of records returned?

Comment: Oops! That's what I get for not testing my answers. Thanks @JW웃

Comment: @SkinnyPipes yep, that too. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using order by with limit in mysql.

select * from table_name order by id desc limit 0,1

Here id is the auto increment value.